# Can't print colored text in the exact middle

Tags: python

```
import shutil
columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
from termcolor import colored

col = colored("test", 'white', 'on_red')
print(f"This is a {col} run".center(columns))
print('this is a test run'.center(columns))
```

For the above code, if i run it, the two lines of output don't have the same indentation.

```
                                                  This is a test run                                                  
                                                         this is a test run
```

i expect they can have the same vertical alignment. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the behavior of f-string vs `str.format()` is similar:

```
print(f"This is a {col} run".center(columns))
print('this is a {} run'.format(col).center(columns))
```

This will produce a constant indent.
Now what caused the problem with different indentation:

```
len(col) # is 18
len('test') # is 4
```

all the formats (color + background) that the package `termcolor` is 14

If you want the none format text to have the same indentation:

```
print('this is a {} run'.format('test').center(columns-len(col)+len('test')))
```